# what is the difference between lhu and lbu in MIPS?

Tags: mips, instruction-set

I'm trying to solve some problem from my class, which is asking me about the register and memory addresses, I understand how lw or lb instructions works but I don't understand lhu and lbu.
when $r1 value is a 4000 and following explanation for this problem

- memory address 4000 : CF
- memory address 4001 : 10
- memory address 4002 : F2
- memory address 4003 : A0
- memory address 4004 : 34
- memory address 4005 : 01

in this case..

- lw  $r2 ($1) => CF (by memory indrect addressing I guess)
- lhu $r2 ($1) => ?
- lbu $r2 ($1) => ?
- lw  $r2 2($1) => F2
- lb  $r2 3($1) => A0

I try to solve few problems but I am not sure that's a correct.
please tell me what is the answer and why is that.

Comment: `lhu` is Load Halfword Unsigned and `lbu` is Load Byte Unsigned

Comment: All those instructions are described in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Comment: `lw` will transfer 32-bits aka 4 bytes.  The answer `CF` is only one byte long.